# How to print groupped data in SAS webout file

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

I created a data set as below

```
Custom_Data_Set
Branch | Code | Region | Col_1 | Col_2 | Fee_1 | Fee_2 | Total
 1st      01     East     val     val     150     250     400
 1st      01     East     val     val     100     120     220
 1st      01     East     val     val     130     120     250
 2nd      02     West     val     val     200     250     450
 2nd      02     West     val     val     300     400     700
```

No I want to print this data to my web file in groups like

```
Branch: 1st  Code: 01  Region: East
  Col_1 | Col_2 | Fee_1 | Fee_2 | Total
   val     val    150     250     400
   val     val    100     120     220
   val     val    130     120     250

   Total          380     490     870
Branch: 2nd  Code: 02  Region: West
  Col_1 | Col_2 | Fee_1 | Fee_2 | Total
   val     val    200     250     450
   val     val    300     400     700

   Total          500     650    1150

 GrandTotal       880     1140   2020
```

I can do simple print using

```
data _null_;
put '<html><body><table>';
run;

data _null_;
 put numberOfObservations=;
 set work.Custom_Data_Set nobs=numberOfObservations;
 file _webout; 
 put '<tr>
         <td>'; put Branch ; put'</td>
         <td>'; put Code ; put'</td>
         <td>'; put Col_1 ; put'</td>
         <td>'; put Col_2 ; put'</td>
         <td>'; put Fee_1 ; put'</td>
         <td>'; put Fee_2 ; put'</td>
         <td>'; put Total; put'</td>
         </tr>';
run;

data _null_;
put '<tr>
         <td>Total</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>'; put &Fee_1_total ; put'</td>
         <td>'; put &Fee_2_total ; put'</td>
         <td>'; put &_total; put'</td>
         </tr>
    </table></body></html>';
run;
```

But I'm having trouble printing that in grouping with total and grand total and placing only one entry of branch, code an region of whole group.

We can do grouping using branch and code.

PS: Fee_1_total, Fee_2_total and _total are macro variables that I'm getting by proc sql into statement and assigning them as sum(relevent_column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do the whole thing in one data step.  No need for macro variables or PROC SQL summary code.  Just make sure the data is sorted by your grouping variables.

You can use a DOW loop to iterate the data step once for each BY group. Use `_N_=1` and the variable created by `end=` option on the `set` statement to know when to write beginning and ending.  Use `first.branch` to know when to write the block header row. You can accumulate the sums yourself into new dataset variables and output the total row after the last row in the by group.

```
data _null_;
  file _webout ;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    putlog nobs= comma20. ;
    put
  '<html><body><table>'
    ;
  end;
  do until (last.region) ;
    set have nobs=nobs end=eof;
    by branch code region ;
    if first.region then put
  '<tr><th colspan="5">' Branch= code= region= '</th></tr>'
 /'<tr><th>Col_1</th><th>Col_2</th><th>Fee_1</th><th>Fee_2</th><th>Total</th></tr>'
    ;
    put
  '<tr><td>' col_1 '</td>'
      '<td>' col_2 '</td>'
      '<td>' fee_1 '</td>'
      '<td>' fee_2 '</td>'
      '<td>' total '</td></tr>'
    ;
    sum_1 = sum(sum_1,fee_1);
    sum_2 = sum(sum_2,fee_2);
    sum_t = sum(sum_t,total);
  end;
  put
  '<tr><td colspan="2">Total</td>'
      '<td>' sum_1 '</td>'
      '<td>' sum_2 '</td>'
      '<td>' sum_t '</td></tr>'
   ;
   grand_1+sum_1;
   grand_2+sum_2;
   grand_total+sum_t;
   if eof then put
  '<tr><td colspan="2">GrandTotal</td>'
      '<td>' grand_1 '</td>'
      '<td>' grand_2 '</td>'
      '<td>' grand_total '</td></tr>'
/ '</table></body></html>'
   ;
run;
```

I copied your posted data into a data step to create something to program with. 
 I changed the values of COL_1 and COL_2 to be distinct.

Resulting table looks like this when opened in IE.

[image]

Comment: in do until (last.region) ; Why you use region? Can we use any other column too like(last.Branch)

Comment: Because multiple branches are in one region

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom. You are a huge help for me. Your code is working like a charm. I'm facing a little problem that is my SAS 9.4 is not running scripts after end statement of do loop. It's not printing total and grand total rows. Any idea for possible issue?

Comment: You might need to post a new question with your actual code and problem. The DO loop in this answer is controlled by the LAST.xx variable created because of the BY statement for the SET statement that is inside the loop.  If you don't have the BY statement, or the LAST. variable does not match the variables in the BY statement then you will have trouble.

Comment: I've posted a new question under sas and sas-macro with my actual code

Answer (score 0):

Quote the macro resolution.

```
put "&Fee_1_total";
```

The put statement requires a variable or a quoted string.  The code you posted causes the resolved macro variable in the context of a DATA Step put statement to be a number.

PROC REPORT can also produce the same output:

```
data have;
input 
Branch : $3. Code : Region : $4. Col_1 : $3. Col_2 : $3. Fee_1 Fee_2 Total;
datalines;
 1st      01     East     val     val     150     250     400
 1st      01     East     val     val     100     120     220
 1st      01     East     val     val     130     120     250
 2nd      02     West     val     val     200     250     450
 2nd      02     West     val     val     300     400     700
run;

options nocenter;

title;
proc report data = have;
  by branch code region;
  column col_1 col_2 fee_1 fee_2 total;
  rbreak after / summarize;
run;

* same with variation in titling;
title "#byvar1: #byval1 #byvar2: #byval2 #byvar3: #byval3";
options nobyline;
proc report data = have;
  by branch code region;
  column col_1 col_2 fee_1 fee_2 total;
  rbreak after / summarize;
  format code z2.;
run;

options byline;
```

Comment: how can I set data have equal to my data table instead of writing input.

Comment: The posted code includes a data step to recreate the example you posted as a text table in your question as a SAS dataset.  If you want to try this answer with your data just use one of the `proc report` versions and change the `data=` option to point to your dataset instead of the example dataset.